# Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default android app

Tags: android, email, jakarta-mail

I followed [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-ap) to implement EmailSender using Javamail on Android.

But I am still getting this exception:

> Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465

I am using Android 1.6.
What might cause this problem?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Did you add the following to your AndroidManifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Firewalls?  Networking problems?  Have you tried manually connecting (using a terminal program, or something similar)?

Comment: Yep I did that, it works just fine. 
It does not work through emulator though and the real phone.

Thanks for help.